# How can i delete table using alises on sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

i got

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as idab, b.id_skb as idab FROM skd a, skb b WHERE idab='5'' at line 1** when i try to delete data from id by 2 tables...
> here it is,

```
<?php 

include './../../koneksi.php';
 

$idab= $_GET['idab'];

if (mysqli_query($koneksi, "DELETE a.id_skd as idab, b.id_skb as idab FROM skd a, skb b WHERE idab='$idab' "));{


    echo ('<script> 
        alert("Data Anda Berhasil Dihapus...!!!");
        window.location="http://localhost/administrasi_kelurahan/pengguna/administrator/Riwayat_Notif.php";
        </script>');


}

?>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your query? Do you really want to remove records from two tables at once?

Comment: You can't delete columns, you can only delete rows.

Comment: yes sir, so i want delete record from 2 table at once by each id...

Comment: Is there a relationship between the tables? You only specified one column in the `WHERE` clause, which table is that column in?

Comment: how can sir, anyway i want to delete this record by each id could you give me solution or some example?

Comment: If you want to delete it from both tables, use two `DELETE` queries, don't try to do it in one query.

Comment: i didnt use fk from each table i just want to know how can i delete 2 tables sir..

Comment: how can, could give me sample?

Comment: so the purpose is, i have 2 table in db and i just completly select at once in the page on 1 table html, but when i want to delete at once from 1 table html it notice me some errors... cuz i think i can select at once..... and i made a delete and i try like i do in select....

Comment: 2 delete queries? but anyway how can i fakes 2 id just 1? is aliases does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform two `DELETE` queries, not one. Use a transaction to make it atomic.

```
$stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($koneski, "DELETE FROM skd WHERE idab = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "s", $idab);
$stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($koneski, "DELETE FROM skb WHERE idab = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "s", $idab);
mysqli_query("START TRANSACTION");
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
mysqli_query("COMMIT");
```

I've also shown how to use a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection.

You can't do it in a single query unless there's a relationship between the tables, such as a foreign key. In that case you would probably make use of `ON DELETE CASCADE` to automatically delete from the child table when you delete from the parent table.

If the data is related, you can use a `JOIN`

```
DELETE a, b
FROM skb AS a
JOIN skb_pengikut AS b ON a.id = b.id_skb
WHERE a.id = ?
```

But if you declare `id_skb` as a foreign key with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option, then you just have to do:

```
DELETE FROM skb
WHERE id = ?
```

and it will automatically delete from `id_pengikut`.

Comment: ok sir i'll it...

Comment: sir, you struck these... omg thank you very much sir !!!!!!

Comment: hello sir, may i ask just little?

Comment: the **skb table has a relation** and it is related to the table called **skb_pengikut**, then the skb_pengikut table has **fk** which is **id_skb**, what I want to ask is whether the right addition to the _query delete 2 related tables?_  like I want to **delete the data in the skb table** and I also want the data **fk on the skb_pengikut to also be deleted**.

Comment: Thanks so much sir, you're amazing !!!

Answer (score 0):

When trying to Delete from two tables, you should use a transaction to couple the two seperate delete operations with a clean rollback possibility. Otherwise you might be left with the record deleted in one table an not deleted in the other.
If the two tables a linked by referencial integrety, then first delete it in referencing table an then in the referenced table.

Comment: i just do like these, cuz i make select and it works, so i just want to know does it works in delete....